# Alternatives to selenium for automating data input?

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently using selenium to automate the input of data in to a website. The website never changes, and the fields are always the same with obviously the data differing.

How I want it to work is for the user to already be logged in to the website, they run a script and a new tab opens in their current browser session with the relevant fields having the data in them.

At the moment it opens a new Chrome session (ignoring the login from the previous session), has to log-in to the site, open a new tab, go to the data input page and push the keys from there. This can be a time consuming activity, and I don't like how it has to login each time. Snippet of my code below.

```
req = request.get_json()
jsonify(req)
url1 = "www.loginpage.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url1)

u = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
u.send_keys("username")
u = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
u.send_keys("password")
u = driver.find_element_by_id('loginButton').submit()

driver.execute_script('''window.open("www.datainputpage.com","_blank");''')
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.find_element_by_id('Field1').send_keys(req[0])
driver.find_element_by_id('Field2').send_keys(req[1])
driver.find_element_by_id('Field3').send_keys(req[2])
driver.find_element_by_id('Field4').send_keys(req[3])
```

Is there a way using python I can automate it as mentioned? Opens new tab in current session - fills in fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can use profiles in Chrome. You specify the directory of your profile and all cookies and stuff will be saved in there. So the next time you run it, it should load those same cookies from your previous session and stay logged in.

```
chrome_options = Options() 
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Another possible option is saving the cookies to a json file, then on the next run, load them and set them in the browser.

[Selenium Cookies](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_cookies/)

[Reading & Writing JSON](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/)